# How To Install Cordova 3.0.0 in Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, cordova

I Want To Know How To Install Cordova 3.0.0 In Windows 8 Using Visual Studio 2012.

I Try In Following Method:

Try :

```
Step1:
```

http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/ Using This Link I Download Cordova-3.0.0-src.zip [38MB]

```
Step2:
```

Unzip The Download Folder And unzip The "cordova-wp8" File

```
Step3:
```

[ I Checked For lib Folder But No lib Folder In The Zip,Then I check It For Create Template But There Is No Create Template But The Create Template Present in 2.9.0]

I also Try Download phone gap-master But It's Contain Only 2.9.1 Version

I Need To Install Cordova 3.0.0 Version In My VS 2012 Using Windows  8

Another One Question What Is Difference Between CordovaWP8AppFull and CordovaAP8app Standalone

I Saw This In The Following Website  [in Set up New Project]
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide

Answer (score 0):

Step1 :

```
npm install -g cordova@3.0.0
```

Step2 :

> The repo's root directory contains a createTemplates.bat file. Double-click this to generate two .zip files: CordovaWP7_x_x_x.zip and CordovaWP8_x_x_x.zip, where 3.3.0 is the current version number. To use these files easily in Visual Studio, copy them to My
>   Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates. You are then able to create new Apache Cordova Windows Phone apps from the Visual Studio File → New Project menu.
>
> If you run the batch file from the command line, you can also call it
>   with a parameter to install automatically:
>
> createTemplates.bat -install

cf [Cordova Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide)

Or you can just build your project for WP7/8 via CLI and run the .sln file of the WP7/8 generated project for this platfrom (in the platforms directory)

And for the difference between CordovaWP8AppFull and CordovaWP8AppStandalone :

> 2.2 About the different templates
>
> Apache Cordova for Windows Phone 8 supports 2 different types of
>   templates.
>
> The 'Full' template includes a pre-built dll containing all the
>   framework code for Apache Cordova. This template will create a project
>   that is easy to update, as you can simply replace the JavaScript and
>   .dll in your project and rebuild when a new version comes out. The
>   downside of this approach is that because the dll contains ALL of the
>   Cordova API, it requires all available permissions even if the APIs
>   are not called. When you submit an app to the App store, Microsoft
>   will run a static analyzer against your application, and detect that
>   you require all available permissions, and place a disclaimer on you
>   app that is presented to the user when they choose to install your
>   app. Users may be discouraged if they see a required permission that
>   does not make sense ( ie, why does this drawing program need access to
>   my media library and contacts ).
>
> The 'Stand-Alone' template includes ALL the source code for Apache
>   Cordova. This project is easier to fine-tune to use just the features
>   you need, thereby working around the permissions issues of the 'Full'
>   template, however this type of project will be more difficult to
>   update, as you will need to update individual files within your
>   project and manage any dependancies yourself. In order to exclude an
>   API you are not using, you can simply right-click-select the Command
>   class file in Visual Studio and choose 'do not include in project'.

cf [Cordova Doc](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html)